# Getting an error while installing Groovy

Tags: grails

I am trying to install Grails 2.4.4. I already have JDK 1.8.0_25 on my system . I set the JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME environment variables to jdk and grails path respectively. When i try to create a new file abc using " Grails create-app abc" in command prompt it gets created, but when I try to run the created file(abc) using "grails run-app abc" I am getting the following error: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing: C:/Program Error occurred during the initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument –

Environment Variables

JAVA_HOME =" C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"

GRAILS_HOME ="C:\grails-2.4.3"

PATH ="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin" //Added these two to path variable.

Please help!!

I'm trying to install it on Windows 8.1 machine, Grails 2.4.4, JDK 1.8.0_25

Comment: Please provide explicit details, e.g., how installing etc.

Comment: you mean grails 2.4.4, right?  there are only 2.4 groovy betas.

Comment: I am trying to install Grails 2.4.4. I already have JDK 1.8.0_25 on my system . I set the JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME environment variables to jdk and grails path respectively. When i try to create a new file abc using " Grails create-app abc" in command prompt it gets created, but when I try to run the created file(abc) using "grails run-app abc" I am getting the following error:

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing: C:/Program Error occurred during the initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument

Comment: please add all of this to the question.  then fix the tag from groovy to grails and paste the error message as complete as possible (e.g. run grails with `--debug --stacktrace --verbose`)

Comment: oh, and does it work, if you are using a simple path like e.g. `c:/grails/2.4.4`?

Comment: Yes, it works...but I'm not able to run

Comment: GRAILS_HOME is pointing to the wrong path (2.4.3). Also, there's an extra space char after each of your env. variables.

Comment: Can you let me know where the extra space is?

Comment: How do I strip space from the environment variable??

Comment: He is referring to the JAVA_HOME variable, just delete the space between the " and the letter C.